# Open Graph actions adding problem

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph

I've added test application then created graph action "XXXXX" in that app, then I deleted that application and created new one and tryed to add the same action (cos the action deleted with app I guess) the system did not allow me to add the action and showed me an error that I've already created that action. So I can neither use the action nor create new one.
Can someone help me in this ?

Comment: See this: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7652666/facebook-open-graph-beta-cant-create-action-because-i-already-use-it for the same issue!